# Nuxt + Vuex + Composition API - Difference between using promise and await in actions

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, vuex

I am currently working on a project with Nuxt(2), Vuex and Composition-API. Trying to fetch some "question content" data from an API like this:

```
const questions = computed(() => store.state['questions'].questions)
const { fetch } = useFetch(async () => {
    await store.dispatch('questions/fetchQuestions')
})
fetch()
```

I tried two methods to get the data in `Actions`.
With `await`:

```
async getQuestionDetail({ commit }, slug) {
    const resp = await this.$axios.$get(`${'api/question/' + slug}`)
    commit('setDetail', resp.data)
}
```

With `promise`:

```
async getQuestionDetail({ commit }, slug) {
    this.$axios.$get(`${'api/question/' + slug}`).then((response) => {
        commit('setDetail', response.data)
    })
}
```

When i tried to get data with `await` and go to the page that makes the request it works with no errors.

But when i refresh the page, i got this error:

```
Error: [vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers.
```

When i get the data with a `promise` page works without any problems.

I would like to know what is causing this error even when i don't bind any data.
What is the difference in behavior in these two methods?

Comment: check the browser log before you refresh, you are probably getting an error too

Comment: @Jimmar checked it again and did not found any other errors, sorry